# How access FastAPI swagger on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, fastapi, openapi, swagger-2.0

1 month ago, I used AWS to upload a FastAPI application. There, I could access my application's swagger normally.

Today, using the GCP structure (which uses Swagger 2.0, instead of OpenAPI 3.0), I can no longer access the swagger of our application.

Any suggestions on how to get the app swagger back to use?
I looked at several sources, however, none seem to indicate that it is possible to use swagger in GCP dependencies.

Comment: Where have you deployed your code? What's the path of the swagger URL?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @guillaumeblaquiere
I cannot publish the application address here as it is from my current company. The application runs on a cloud run. As it is a FastAPI application, previously, using the path /docs took me to the Swagger documentation, and today, in GCP, it is not possible to do the same.

Comment: What's you error? 404? 403?

Comment: I am getting the following @guillaumeblaquiere: 
{
  "message": "The current request is not defined by this API.",
  "code": 404
}
Remembering that we've never done nothing different when we deployed in AWS

Comment: Ok, did you try your container on your computer? Are you sure that the URL is listen? I mainly guess an issue in the configuration/packaging of the container. Maybe share your dockerfile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253851/discussion-between-magaren-and-guillaume-blaquiere).

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm the following:

1. check your api deploy successfully. (**green tick**)
2. Make sure your `Authentication` is `Authenticated` which let you can access the api without mail authenticated
   [image]
3. Access `your_url/docs`
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer JunXiang, but what would I do with authenticated endpoints? The main problem is related that I can't access the organic-made FastAPI /docs from GCP, and I think It's not related to Authentication...